# How to create dynamic URLs in sitemap.xml using angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, xml-sitemap

How to create dynamic URLs in sitemap.xml using angular 2?. I have tried with npm sitemap package. But i cannot create sitemap.xml. can anyone tell how to to create dynmic urls in angular 2?

Comment: from sitemap-generator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator >This package don't care what frameworks and technologies you are using under the hood. The only requirement is, that your URL's return valid HTML. Therefore SSR (server side rendering) is required for single page apps as no JavaScript is executed.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The better solution is to generate your sitemap dynamically with a nodejs worker, created by yourself. Nodejs can write a file in system and is pretty simple to generate file.